# Why can an Oracle SET UNUSED COLUMN cause internal UPDATE SET X=X and huge log generation?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

On Oracle 11.2.0.4.1, we tried to run a simple `ALTER TABLE PARTITIONED_LARGE SET UNUSED COLUMN XXXXX;` on a large ref-partitioned child table to decommission a column.

The table has hundreds of millions of rows across thousands of partitions. Most partitions have been truncated and no segments left; probably about 220 of them have data. As per standard practice the point of the SET UNUSED COLUMN was to avoid redo generation and long downtime, while allowing us to regain space moving forward.

Something seems to have gone horribly awry; it started generating dozens of GB of redo logs; eventually filling up UNDOTBS; then failed with the below and started rolling back.

```
Fri Apr 24 23:48:13 2015
ORA-01555 caused by SQL statement below (SQL ID: 1ksq8yfdxv3ys, Query Duration=13500 sec, SCN: 0x0b5b.6392295a):
update "SCHEMA"."PARTITIONED_LARGE" set "XXXXX" = "XXXXX"
```

Seeing the statement above it's pretty obvious why it's generating undo/redo, but why did Oracle decide internally to do such an update during a SET UNUSED COLUMN?!

Other points that may or may not be relevant

- at the time the command was started, a restore point had been created for flashback purposes. This restore point was dropped part way through when flashback log size became a problem
- the column is defined as BINARY_DOUBLE DEFAULT 0 CONSTRAINT XXXXX_NN NOT NULL
- the SET UNUSED had been earlier tested on a test DB with about 75% of the data of the DB in question (but not exactly the same data) and had no issues; ran within seconds.

Can anyone explain this behaviour, either in terms of expected behaviour or known issues?

Comment: All it is supposed to do is set an internal flag.... I'd open an SR with Oracle on this one. As an aside, is it actually doing any harm? It might cause you problems in the future if you do any partition exchange operations. Might be doing it just to make sure there's no NULL rows (seeing as it is defined as NOT NULL), for some odd reason. Sorry, just thinking aloud :)

Comment: Was the column added later? How was the test database created? What other differences are there between the test database and this one? What happens on the test database if you create a restore point for flashback and run the `set unused` statement there?

Comment: @Phil Yes, we are indeed raising an SR with Oracle. Eventually the rollback from the failure above succeeded (after about 9 hours!?) and the column is in tact. It's doing harm only insofar as we want to set it unused to reclaim space going forward. Our partitions are essentially done by date, and we drop old ones, so if I understand correctly we will gradually regain space. Actually, I came across [this MOS bug](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1611785.1&id=17325413.8&_adf.ctrl-state=15wmha5mvp_1229&_afrLoop=164465136311848) which looks related.

Comment: @Colin Yes the column was added post-initial table creation; relying on the Oracle magic for adding `NOT NULL` columns with a `DEFAULT` to avoid hitting the disk during the `ADD COLUMN`. As I understand, the test DB was created with a direct RMAN load from a prod backup. Unfortunately, the test DB is 11.2.0.4.3 c.f prod on 11.2.0.4.1 so there could be a clue there. We will probably need to do a fresh restore into the test DB as see if we can replicate though; with restore point and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle said it wasn't a known issue, and basically asked us to re-run with tracing on. Unfortunately on a large production database, and given large downtime required to rollback last time, this wasn't really an option.

We had suspicion that it is related to [this bug](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=21594178973154&parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1611785.1&id=17325413.8&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=94j1ub5b_4) fixed in 11.2.0.4.**2**

```
Bug 17325413 - Drop column with DEFAULT value and NOT NULL definition ends up with dropped column data hitting disk leading to corruption (Doc ID 17325413.8)

This problem is introduced in 11.2.0.4 and 12.1.0.1 by the fix for bug 14222244

Drop of a column with a DEFAULT value and a NOT NULL definition ends up with dropped column 
data being written to disk leading to block corruptions.
This causes problems for generating undo which cannot be applied; a ROLLBACK fails.

Rediscovery Notes
 If a NOT NULLable column added via "add column optimization" is writing to disk, then it
 is likely you have run into the bug.

 This can result in block corruption causing ORA-600 block check errors with check code 
 errors 6264, 6110, or 6103 when db_block_checking is enabled:
  ORA-600 [kdBlkCheckError] [file#] [block#] [6264] --> needs _db_block_check_for_debug to catch it.  This is a ZLC logical corruption (Zero Length Column instead of NULL) 
  ORA-600 [kdBlkCheckError] [file#] [block#] [6110]
  ORA-600 [kdBlkCheckError] [file#] [block#] [6103]

or other internal errors when db_block_checking is not enabled like ORA-600 [13013], ORA-600 [17182] or external errors like ORA-12899.

Workaround

 Note that once error occurs, table has to be rebuilt: 
   Note:1527738.1 may skip the rows affected and can be used with _disable_block_checking=false as:
      alter session set "_disable_block_checking"=true;
       and in the same session use the PLSQL in Note:1527738.1 section "SKIP ORA-600 in a Table"
```

After patch to 11.2.0.4.**6** the `SET UNUSED` ran fine in production without the unexpected log production. Might be worth a go if anyone else stumbles into this problem; although I suspect Oracle will eventually have to raise a proper bug for this issue once someone helps them narrow it down properly.